# NoIR Pi Camera settings for night sky timelapse

Tags: raspicam

I have a Pi NoIR camera and have been trying to timelapse film the night sky. I'm looking for the kind of effect you see where the stars all rotate across the screen in a half moon shape.

I have all the timelapse still and encoding the stills into a video working no problem. However the results are poor at best.

So, my question is; is the Pi NoIR suitable for this type of project, and if so is there a particular package (raspicam ?) that I should be using and, are there particular settings (exposure etc) that I should be experimenting for best results.

Comment: An interesting blog article about the subject: http://www.mccarroll.net/blog/startrails/

Comment: I am not at all an expert but to make a guess I'd say the NoIR camera might be *detrimental* because IR light is more likely to be ambient and wash out the stars in the long exposures you need to capture them...

Comment: Ja I agree with that. Imagine the people doing this as professionals. They use camera like Canon 1D,3D,5D - Do they use a NoIR filter? Nein! You will make better effort by using a normal camera. You must also set your expore at midnigh [so that average it looks good] - Also, light pollution is bad too

Comment: I check that image on the blog. The ISO being used on that is toooo much! Terrible noise allover the picture. You can make it better by setting exposure longer with lower ISO. But is it possible with Pi Cam? Maybe not, that is why there is so much noise. And there is too much light pollution too

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @WillyWonka - I'll be trying out a normal camera and a NoIR camera and post the results here.